# crunching data with array.map or array.filter

Tags: javascript, arrays

My endpoint delivers data like this:

```
[{
    "category": "square",
    "color": "blue",
    "groups": [{
        "side": "left",
        "group_id": "212"
      }, {
        "side": "left",
        "group_id": "213"
      }]
  },{
    "category": "square",
    "color": "red",
    "groups": [{
        "side": "left",
        "group_id": "212"
      },{
        "side": "right",
        "group_id": "215"
      }]
}]
```

What I want to do is get a tally of users  by `category` and `color` per the same `side` and `group_id` values. So I'd end up with an array of objects maybe like this:

```
[{
        "group_id": "212",
        "side": "left",
        "category": "square",
        "color": "blue",
        "total": 1
    },{
        "group_id": "212",
        "side": "left",
        "category": "square",
        "color": "red",
        "total": 1
    },{
     // etc [truncated]
}]
```

I have one `group_id` known at a time (ie "212"). Every entry's group object can vary (how many, the order), so `user.groups[0]` wouldn't necessarily be the `user.groups.group_id` in question. But I won't have the total number of group_ids, and looping through seems excessive, anyway.

In pseudo-code, I'm thinking the logic would go something like:

```
- for each object:
  - create object with category and color
  - push group values into object
  - if 2nd group, create 2nd obj, push group
- result: a whole bunch of objects, each with category/color/side/group_id
- get all objects with group_id
- ?? find unique keys, to iterate through?
- ?? iterate & check if key matches existing in array, increase count?
```

Array.filter doesn't seem to fit this use case (at least going by examples I can find), and array.map seems to be used to reduce things, not match things (not sure). Is there an efficient way to crunch this data to set up groups by the properties and sub-properties, so I can get a total count of each?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds similar to d3js's nest() http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/. I know you didn't ask for other libraries, but you could examine how they accomplish it if you didn't want to use it.

Comment: **and again by age**. Where is age in your structure?

Comment: doh. right, sorry, will edit the typo. :)

Comment: Why doesn't your sample result have groups 213 or 215?

Comment: I was truncating for space, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention "efficient" then it's worth noting that in Javascript using `for` loops is almost always more performant then using `.map()`, `.reduce()`, `.filter()` or other methods which use a callback for iteration.

Here's an example:

```
var result = {}
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
  var item = data[i]
  for (var i2 = 0, len = item.groups.length; i2 < len; i2++) {
    var group = item.groups[i2]

    var key = [group.group_id, group.side, item.category, item.color].join()

    var x = result[key] || {
        group_id: group.group_id,
        side: group.side,
        category: item.category,
        color: item.color,
        total: 0
      }
      ++x.total
    result[key] = x
  }
}

// convert result to an array
var results = []
for (var p in result) {
  if (result.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
    results.push(result[p])
  }
}

return results
```

Comment: I added a check for `group.group_id` == `group_id` (or else I got every group in each call), and I realized it gives me uniques of color/category/side, instead of color/side, category/side. I can tweak that more. But most importantly, I didn't realize for loops were fastest. Guess I've heard too much "for loops are for beginners" attitude and assumed I had to level up. I'll go with fast. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would probably solve this problem with reduce.  I am assuming you are going after data of a specific side and group_id here.

```
var side = 'left';

var group_id = '212';


data.reduce(function(accumulator, currentObject) {

  var resultObj = {
    count: 0, 
    side: side, 
    group_id: group_id, 
    color: currentObject.color, 
    category: currentObject.category
  };

  currentObject.groups.forEach(function(object) {
    if (object.group_id === group_id && object.side === side) {
      resultObj.count++
    }
  });

  accumulator.push(resultObj);

  return accumulator;

}, []);
```

Comment: Do I need to declare `accumulator` at the start? And is `currentObject` each object w/in the array? iow, I'd need to run this on each object w/in my array?

Comment: So reduce iterates over each element in your array and invokes the callback function on each element.  Whatever the callback returns becomes the accumulator for the next iteration, and if there are no more iterations, the accumulator is returned as the result of the reduce function.  For my function above, I set the accumulator to start as an array (the third argument to reduce on the last line there), and then I add more and more objects to it as I go.

Answer (score 1):

For each element of your array you want to add its category and color information to each element of its groups, and then collect all elements of all groups together in one big array.  So you want to map over the elements, and for each element you want to map over its group, and then finally you want to concatenate all the groups.  Like so:

```
var data = [{category: "square",
             color: "blue",
             groups: [{side: "left", group_id: "212"},
                      {side: "left", group_id: "213"}]},
            {category: "square",
             color: "red",
             groups: [{side: "left", group_id: "212"},
                      {side: "right", group_id: "215"}]}]

var output = [].concat.apply([], data.map(
    function(obj){
        return obj.groups.map(
            function(o){
                o.category = obj.category;
                o.color = obj.color;
                return o;
            });
    }));
```